# Axios sending double CSRF-Token [CSRF-Token mismatch]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a basic laravel/vue with sanctum implementation. The problem is straight forward:

I'm sending a token-request and logging-in the user. The server sends back a new token. Axios adds this token, but adds another token that is always the same and expired.

Code:

```
await APIClient.get("/sanctum/csrf-cookie")
return APIClient.post("/api/user/login", payload);
```

DevTools/Network tab:

- csrf-cookie request => `response-headers` has the valid `XSRF-TOKEN`
- login request => `request-headers`, `SET-COOKIE` property has `XSRF-TOKEN` (old expired value) `;` `laravel_session` `;` `XSRF-TOKEN` (new valid value)

My problem is with the old value. There's no place in my code for this to be added at all.

This's my axios client

```
const APIClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: constants.PATHS.url,
    withCredentials: true, // required to handle the CSRF token
});
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an actual solution. You should clear the cookies of the document whenever you logout, in this way, the token will always be the new one and the old one cannot be duplicated. I've seen this bug happens in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't quite understand your question, do you not know how to add (old expired value) or (new valid value) to the header of axios?
I recommend using axios as a property of window. It is easier to change its properties:

```js
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['token'] = "aaa"; //add a header
```

Comment: I do understand, but the `request-headers` look like this: `SET-COOKIE: XSRF-TOKEN: OLD; laravel_session: VAL; XSRF-TOKEN: NEW` and the first property is taken and the last one is ignored.